# Why doesn't office.js work when locally referenced?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, office365api, office-js, javascript-api-for-office

I have a perfectly functioning add in based on the code on GitHub titled LoadingAndWritingOOXMLWeb, but with a fair few modifications.
But I am wanting to demo offline - or at least in a place where the network is not reliable enough to be trusted.
So I open the URL https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js
and save as office.js, copy the file to the same folder as my html file, then alter the reference as follows:

```
<!-- <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->


<script src="office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Save, flush cache etc.
Now when I click to add, get a moment of timeglass in Office but nothing inserts.
Alter the code back and it happily inserts again.

The file isn't blocked, and can be opened using view source in the Chrome, browsing from the HTML to the js file, so it is accessible.
When I compare, what I see from my code with the original from Microsoft in Chrome view source the contents look exactly the same.

Am I missing something obvious?
thanks for any help.

Comment: Check inside the javascript file, it could be referencing another file etc. Also `f12` these things in your browser to see console log output!

Comment: That js is trying to load other script files.  Use browser dev tools network tab to see what other files it's trying to read.

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of other files which it needs. Office.js mostly figures out what client is hosting it and then loads the appropriate files specific for that client (for example, stuff like "outlook-web-16.00.js").

The Visual Studio templates include a complete set of files for offline use, or, you could take a look at the network tab in your browser when loading from the hosted version and grab those files too.

Comment: You can also grab the list of files from Nuget:  http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.js/

Comment: The script office.js turned out to have references to Word-15.js, Excel etc. By downloading the latest 1.1 version of the Office js api using git etc I was able to get all the required files and all now works fine.

Comment: Be careful with Nuget version of Microsaoft.Office.js. We recently learned they are not kept up-to-date. Check the comment section of accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511026/highlight-bindings-in-a-document#comment64459291_38515230

Comment: Is there any officially documented list of files needed? (ie., for Excel or Word or..... add-ins) I know it also depends on the parts of the API being used but a comprehensive guide would help. Adding the files required by office.js (according to the network tab in the browser) doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/office-js

This package is meant for offline usage.

> The NPM package for Office.js is a copy of what gets published to the official "evergreen" Office.js CDN, at https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js.
>
> The Office.js CDN contains all currently available Office.js APIs at any moment in time.
>
> Each Office.js NPM package contains only Office.js APIs available on the Office.js CDN when the NPM package version was created.