# Highlight bindings in a document

Tags: javascript, excel, ms-word, office-js

I have an Office Add-in using JavaScript API for Office 1.1. I am trying to highlight bindings in a Word document and bindings to cells in Excel documents so the user can easily recognize them.

I see the API allows formatting of TableBindings using setFormatsAsync but mine are Matrix and Text. I don't use Table type because it adds a header row and the total row messes up my logic.

Is there a way to format or highlight the bindings?

I will prefer this to be temporary - similar to the way the background color changes a bit when you hover on top of the binding but I can live with coloring the text and then removing the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options here. To highlighting with formatting, use the [RangeFormat](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/rangeformat) object to modify the outline, background, or other properties. Here's the code for a background fill:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
    var myRange = ctx.workbook.bindings.getItem("myBinding").getRange();
    myRange.format.fill.color = "FFFF00";
    return ctx.sync(); 
});
```

Alternatively, you can draw the user's attention by causing their selection to move to the binding:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
    var myRange = ctx.workbook.bindings.getItem("myBinding").getRange();
    myRange.select();
    return ctx.sync(); 
});
```

Finally, if you want the code above to work in Excel 2013 too, you can accomplish the same thing with this snippet:

```
var myDoc = Office.context.document;
myDoc.goToByIdAsync("myBinding", Office.GoToType.Binding, function (asyncResult) {});
```

-Michael Saunders, program manager for Office add-ins

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It works with CDN but my local package from Nuget (Microsoft.Office.js.1.1.0.9) does not load excel-win32-16.00.debug.js. So, I don't have access to Excel object.

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? 2013 doesn't support the Excel object.

Comment: I use Office 2016 on Win 10. When I run the project in VS 2015, in Solution Explorer/Script Documents I see excel-15.01.debug.js and office.debug.js only. I don't think the Excel.run function is there. When I search for it, it is in excel-web-16.00.debug.js and excel-win32-16.00.debug.js, which I don't see loaded. Is office.debug.js supposed to load the appropriate libraries?

Comment: Your package is probably out of date then. If you'd like to run it locally, just copy the CDN files or download a more recent package.

Comment: Nuget has this as the latest. I see inside the CDN files they are a bit ahead. I will probably do the CDN copy but updating will kill me in the future. (P.S. I am really glad you guys help the Office add-in developers here.)

Comment: Ah, Nuget - the latest API versions aren't there. See this page for how to get all the latest tools and resources for development: http://dev.office.com/getting-started/addins?product=excel#build

Comment: Thank you, Michael! I need to stay in touch with you somehow because we are in the long run with Office add-ins.